# How to use config file while generating certificate in .NET?

Tags: x509certificate2, .net-4.8

I have a .cnf file for certificate generating, but i didn't find method, which can help me to use it in certificate generating. How i can do it?

I've tried to import it into X509CertificateBasicConstraintExtension, but i got exception of bad asn1 encoding data...

Comment: .NET('s X509 classes) do(es) not use `.cnf` files.  If you're trying to convert OpenSSL .cnf files, you'll have to either write a converter yourself, or just change the data from the file into API calls in .NET.

Comment: API? What do you mean? Call cmd into my app ?

Comment: [API](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/API): Application Programming Interface.  Classes/structs/methods/functions/subroutines/etc.